# Can I write UDF inside an Evaluate formula strings in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have defined the next formula to enter it as an Array Formula:
    =IF(LenTableRange(Hoja1!$B$15)=Hoja1!$B$4,IF(OFFSET(LenTableRange(Hoja1!$A$15),0,5)="",LenTableRange(Hoja1!$A$15)))

For some extra info:
- LenTableRange returns a range object, the body of the function is:

```
'Passing a cell as a range, it returns
Function LenTableRange(R As Range) As Range
   Application.Volatile
   Set LenTableRange = Range(R, R.End(xlDown))
End Function
```

The data i'm taking is Strings in $A$15 > column, numbers in $B$15 > column. Both columns can have repeated values, that's why I filter it, and the column that  referes to OFFSET(LenTableRange($B$15);0;5) referes to dates, that could have no value or empty cell.

As you see it has a user defined function in it.
The UDF 'LenTableRange' works fine.
When I enter the whole formula or the name into a cell it works fine, but when I try the following in VBA:

```
'I think I have to escape the double quotes as so.
Dim StrForm As String
StrForm = "=IF(LenTablaRango(Hoja1!$B$15)=Hoja1!$B$4,IF(OFFSET(LenTablaRango(Hoja1!$A$15),0,5)="""""",LenTablaRango(Hoja1!$A$15)))"

Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(StrForm)
```

It gives error 2015.
I suspect it is not reading UDFs inside the formula properly.
Is it really possible to do this?
What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: What's in `Hoja1!$A$15` and `Hoja1!$B$15`?

Comment: Also what does `LenTablaRango` return? A `Range` object?

Comment: Note: both `IF` functions are missing a `value_if_false` argument.

Comment: Not that it solves anything (kind of tangential), but stumbled across [this article](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/) which mentions the limitations of `Application.Evaluate`. I'm not sure I'd go the route you're trying to go.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon But Value_If_false are optionals, aren't they?
I'll update the question with the information you asked for.